# Why does VSCode doesnt change virtual environment from terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So, via the anaconda prompt I created an environment and then installed numpy

```
conda -n CT_Bioinformatics python=3.6
conda install numpy
```

And it is installed
Then on VSCode (where python interpreter is installed) I changed the interpreter to the one in the Enviroment's folder and it displayed the correct version on the bottom left. When I try to run a file from the terminal it says numpy is not installed and after I created a new file:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

The following appeared:

```
3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Only when I run a file by right clicking and selecting to Run Python File it actually works and displays the right version.

```
PS C:\CT Bioinformatics Coursework> & C:/Anaconda/envs/CT_Bioinformatics/python.exe "c:\CT Bioinformatics Coursework\dp_template.py"
```

I read that you can put in the settings:

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\CT_Bioinformatics\\python.exe"
```

But it is still the same. Is there anything I am missing so that I can just do python filename on the terminal(so it uses the correct version)?
Thanks

Comment: Any news on this? I'm having this same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Verify in settings that:

```
// Activate Python Environment in Terminal created using the Extension.
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

Default value is true. Then open the terminal with command "Python: Create Terminal". It creates a terminal and activates your python environment.

Comment: Yeah I had that put in after I saw it in one forum. When I do Python:Create Terminal it says: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Both are on the newest version

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. My solution is in the terminal console in VScode, type and run

> `& c:/Users/dell/Anaconda3/envs/a_env_name/python.exe`

instead of traditional

> `python`